# Can the smart contracts guarantee that I can get the coffee that I paid in cryptocurrency?

Tags: trust

Let's assume that there is no any protection from any authority, government or law. They are completely absent.

Can the smart contracts guarantee that I can get the coffee in the real world that I paid in cryptocurrency and also guarantee that the seller can get the money after I received the coffee?

Answer (score 1):

As long the Ethereum network is there, yes.

But if your contract let's say use token, or ETH itself, people will still need to rely on any type of exchangesto get or sell back the crypto to real fiat money.

Comment: @Hari GTT Psicolabis  You can fetch external data using Oracle thing (I never used, just read about). Also, in the context, a contract or ETH itself could be used to pay a coffee and watch for event on the blockchain to guaranteed the fund where sent for the good from buyer to seller, once confirmed. It's quite the goal of a cryptocurrency, not? :)

Answer (score 1):

No. The smart contract can only act based on states of the EVM. They can warantee efects inside the EVM, but the effects on the real world are outside of it's scope.